# Как подгрузить видео файл когда плеер делают на полный экран?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

У меня есть такой video tag c отдержкой lazy load.
И есть два видео.

Одно для preview с низким расширением, второе в хорошем качестве.

Как мне подгрузить видео в хорошем качестве, когда пользователь разворачивает плеер на весь экран ?

```
 <video class = "lazy" controls preload="none" poster="/static/html/components/varan-gallery/icons/preview.jpeg">
          <source src="/static/html/components/varan-gallery/icons/preview.jpeg" data-src="/static/html/components/varan-gallery/icons/preview.webm" type="video/webm">
          <source src="/static/html/components/varan-gallery/icons/full.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
```

Comment: не думали использовать 2 тега видео и менять их?

Comment: не думал, я сейчас разбираюсь с этим.
Пример где я увидел такую запись взят отсюда.
По этому хотелось бы понять, как авторы статьи это сделали.
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/lazy-loading-guidance/images-and-video/
А как мне отследить изменение видео на полный экран ?